# Custom build for Dojo 1.7.1 with Layer and CSS Optimization

Tags: build, dojo

With Dojo 1.6.x it was quite easy to create a custom build. In the end I only needed to include a dojo.js file, my application layer file and an optimized css file with all the styles. Simple and easy.

But with Dojo 1.7.x I don't get it. My goal is just to include an opmtimized dojo.js file, my application layer file with all my widgets and stuff and an optmized css file.

Here is my profile.js

```
var profile = {
releaseDir: "./release",
basePath: "..",
action: "release",
cssOptimize: "comments",
mini: true,
optimize: "closure",
layerOptimize: "closure",
stripConsole: "all",
selectorEngine: "acme",
packages:[
    {
        name: "dojo",
        location: "./sources/dojo"
    },
    {
        name: "dijit",
        location: "./sources/dijit"
    },
    {
        name: "dojox",
        location: "./sources/dojox"
    }
],
layers: {
    "dojo/dojo": {
        name: "myDojo.js",
        include: [ "dojo/dojo" ],
        boot: true,
        dependencies: [ "dojo/parser", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore", "dijit/themes/tundra", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Form", "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/CheckBox", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dijit/form/NumberSpinner", "dijit/form/Textarea", "dijit/form/TextBox", "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox", "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/TabContainer", "dijit/Tooltip", "dojox/widget/ColorPicker" ]
    }
},
resourceTags: {
    amd: function (filename, mid) {
        return /\.js$/.test(filename);
    }
}
```

};

When I run the build a release is created. I found the dojo.js which has the size of about 580 KB uncompressed. But I did not fond my application file and the compressed css file with all styles.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, Ralf

Answer (score 1):

Your layer specification seems to be incorrect. Try this instead:

```
layers: {
    "dojo/myDojo": {
        include: [ "dojo/parser", "dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
                   "dijit/themes/tundra", "dijit/Dialog", "dijit/form/Form",
                   "dijit/form/Button", "dijit/form/CheckBox",
                   "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
                   "dijit/form/FilteringSelect", "dijit/form/NumberSpinner",
                   "dijit/form/Textarea", "dijit/form/TextBox",
                   "dijit/form/TimeTextBox", "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
                   "dijit/layout/ContentPane", "dijit/layout/TabContainer",
                   "dijit/Tooltip", "dojox/widget/ColorPicker"
                 ],
        boot: true
    }
},
```

**References**

- http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/build/
- http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.7/build/